# how do I change textField keyboard to be Arabic numbers only? Swift / UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to make my text field show only Arabic numbers keyboard, no matter what language the device have. I changed the app base language to Arabic and it is still showing me English numbers.

[keyboardImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9f70.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a subclass like `ArabicTextField` of `UITextField` and use `textInputMode` property to change your keyboard as below

```
class ArabicTextField: UITextField {
    override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {
        UITextInputMode.activeInputModes.filter
        { $0.primaryLanguage == "ar" }.first ?? super.textInputMode } 
}
```